# Rails download objects from amazon bucket s3 aws-sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, controllers

I'm new to RoR.

I'm creating a small app that uploads, deletes and downloads mp3 objects from an s3 bucket. (using aws-sdk gem).

I can't manage to create the right download controller. My app is downloading a text file called download with the Object reference from s3 ( Aws::S3::Object:0x007feb59782368 ).

All help will be appreciated!

This is my code:

controller >

```
  def download
    bucket = S3.bucket(S3_BUCKET.name)
    obj = bucket.object(params[:song])
    byebug
    send_data obj
  end
```

view >

```
<%= link_to "download", "songs/download/?song=" + song.name %>
```

And the response from byebug:

```
(byebug) send_data obj
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Sent data  (2.2ms)
"#<Aws::S3::Object:0x007fc3b1323c60>"
(byebug)
```

Comment: have you tried reading out the object? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/downloading-objects-from-amazon-s3-using-the-aws-sdk-for-ruby/

Comment: I've checked that link countless times this morning and I can't make my controller work... .read doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried writing the object to a temp file and then using send_file? I have found that to be highly effective. and what do you mean read doesn't work?

Comment: I'd consider sending an HTTP 302 to the S3 url and having the client download the object directly from S3. By having your app server proxy the response it means your rails app processes are going to be tied up while they buffer the object from s3 and then have to send it down the pipe

Answer (score 0):

Try using `send_file` instead of `send_data`

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider sending an HTTP 302 to the S3 url and having the client download the object directly from S3. By having your app server proxy the response it means your rails app processes are going to be tied up while they buffer the object from s3 and then have to send it down the pipe. If security (and not wanting to expose the s3 objects publicliy) is a concern then keep them private and generate a signed URL to the objects with a short-ish expiration date.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to create a link with the source of the file. When they click on that link, it will open in a new tap and download automatically from S3.

The other option would be to work with the download functionality but I didn't read the docs yet.